# How to clear the timer in my function?

Tags: javascript, timer

All the material related with this issue are here.

[All the material related with this issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fn744iq8r0t5dqv/p1.zip?dl=0)

Open the p1.html, snow will fly automatically.
Click `stop button` can't stop the flying sonw.

Maybe the `clearInterval(timer);`  in stopFly  function can't run.
How to fix it?

Part of js.

```
function stopFly(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = "";
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = "disabled";
}

window.onload=function(){
    createManySnow();
    setInterval(startFly,100);
}
```

Part of html.

```
<input type="button" value="new" onclick="createManySnow();">
<input type="button" id="startButton"  value="start"  onclick="timer=setInterval(startFly,100)">
<input type="button" id="stopButton"     value="stop" onclick="stopFly();">
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the return value of `setInterval` to `timer` in your `onload` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign the `timer` variable in your `onload` function. So an interval is running without a pointer.

```
window.onload = function () {
    createManySnow();
    window.timer = setInterval(startFly, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign to a variable the timer you created.

```
let startFlyInterval;
function stopFly(){
    clearInterval(startFlyInterval);
    document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = "";
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = "disabled";
}

window.onload = function(){
    createManySnow();
    startFlyInterval = setInterval(startFly, 100);
}
```

Comment: You are never reading from `startFlyInterval`. This doesn't fix the OP's problem.